# Can I modify box in existing PDF file with HummuJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I need to change exisiting PDF files with some new data. HummusJS docs says that I can change box with parsing and modification. But I cant find a right method for this.

Maybe someone faced with this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "box with parsing and modification"?

Comment: @CristianSmocot I mean that with pasing I can find right box and modify

Comment: So you want to modify a "box" within a PDF file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this example from the wiki of the HummusJS project
**https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/blob/master/tests/ModifyingExistingFileContent.js**

Pay attention to the function **testPageSizeModification** on line 4

Comment: Affraid that this is not exactly what I want, because I need to change text

Comment: when i run this file nothing changes on my terminal , nor on the file structure